# How to create a user namespace in Ubuntu?

Tags: namespace

I want to create namespaces with and without the privilege and need to study the implications if the namespace creation is restricted only for the privileged users.

How to create a user namespace in Ubuntu 18.04LTS. Which command I should use?

Comment: What goal do you want to achieve by introducing a namespace?

Comment: @Philippos, I want to create namespaces with and without the privilege and need to study the implications if the namespace creation is restricted only for the privileged users.

Comment: Generally, the answer to "how do I create a namespace?" is `unshare`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unshare -U` creates a `user name space` and `unshare -n` create a `network namespace`